# How to allow comma to my addition codes

Tags: javascript, html

These code are working; adding correctly. The problem is that if I want to add 99000000.00 + 199000000.00 it displays 298000000.00.

How can I make it 99,000,000.00 + 199,000,000.00 that displays 298,000,000.00?

Every time I compute numbers with comma, it results to NAN/Invalid. But if I compute numbers without comma, it computes well. How to allow comma in text area/numbers inputted by the users without having a NAN/Invalid result?

Please see code used below:

HTML CODE:

```
<table width="460" border="1">

                  <tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td>SOUTH CLUSTER (391)</td>
                        <td><input name="scc" type="text" size="25" id="scc" value="0.00"/></div></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td>CENTRAL CLUSTER(387)</td>
                        <td><input name="ccc" type="text" size="25" id="ccc" value="0.00" /></div></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td>NORTH CLUSTER(393)</td>
                        <td><input name="ncc" type="text" size="25" id="ncc" value="0.00"  /></div></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td >C HUB(390)</td>
                        <td><input name="vch" type="text" size="25" id="vch" value="0.00"/></div></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td>CH HUB(397)</td>
                        <td><input name="mch" type="text" size="25" id="mch" value="0.00"/></div></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td>NLC HUB(399)</td>
                        <td><input name="nlch" type="text" size="25" id="nlch" value="0.00"/></div></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td>SLC HUB(396)</td>
                        <td><input name="slch" type="text" size="25" id="slch" value="0.00"/></div></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td>
                        <td><div class="style66" align="center"><input type="button" value="ADD" onclick="civ()"></center></td>
                        </tr>
```

JAVASCRIPT CODES:

```
function civ(){
civ1=Number(document.addition.scc.value);
civ2=Number(document.addition.ccc.value);
civ3=Number(document.addition.ncc.value);
civ4=Number(document.addition.vch.value);
civ5=Number(document.addition.mch.value);
civ6=Number(document.addition.nlch.value);
civ7=Number(document.addition.slch.value);
valNum1=Math.floor((civ1+civ2+civ3+civ4+civ5+civ6+civ7)*100)/100;
document.addition.civ123.value=valNum1;
}
```

Comment: Just clean out the commas from the string before conversion.

Comment: Please see [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20455/is-it-wrong-to-use-the-word-codes-in-a-programming-context/) if you want to be taken seriously, and learn a little about data types. Expect to be frequently downvoted until you learn to put in a little more effort yourself.

Comment: What I mean is that if you put in a bit more effort then 1/ you will learn more, 2/ more people will be willing to help and 3/ you'll get less people flaming you or downvoting. We all started somewhere, but you'll learn more if you do your own research, such as reading language tutorials and documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have commas, it is Not a Number (NaN).

A quickfix would be to add in a function to convert them to a number

```
function NumWithComma(num){
    return parseInt(num.replace(",",""));
}
```

then  do

```
civ1 = NumWithComma(document.addition.scc.value);
```

This is a quickfix, in my opinion there are many things wrong with what you have posted...hopefully this helps somehow

Comment: HI!! IT works! It allows comma(,) already! :)) If I input 123,456.00 and 123, 234.00.. it now adding! :) Before its not bcoz it doesn't allow commas. ;p Yehey, thanks to this one! However, when its added, the result doesn't show comma. :( ex: 1,111.00 + 1,222.00 = 2333.00.. not 2,333.00 :( But hey, thanks much!

Comment: no worries. If this is the approach you are going to use, it might be worth it to look for spaces (" ") as well. Also, with a quick google search I found this http://www.mredkj.com/javascript/nfbasic.html Has a function that adds commas to numbers...might be useful

Comment: Hi, yes neolaser! Thanks so much. :) Your codes works perfectly. :) I can't even tell them what I need or I cnt give them what they wanna see but thanks for TRYING to understand me. :) Your codes are awesome and I dont have to worry anymore coz its all working well. ;p Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Use replace to clean the commas:

```
number_with_commas.replace(/,/g, '');
```

Or to clean everything that is not a digit or a decimal point:

```
number_with_random_noise.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '');
```

Comment: I like your second idea, cleaning out everything you don't want. Though if a user enters something like "1a2b3" in a field that is clearly intended for numbers I think it is probably better to give a validation error than assume they meant "123".

Comment: Maybe something like num=num.replace(/[\s,]/g, ''); if(num.test(/[^0-9.]/)) { //not a valid number, do something }. This replaces any space characters and , but keeps the rest intact.

Comment: Hi thanks thomasa88 and nnnnnn ;)) Its already coded that asdfjweiorw and %&^&**(*() and 123heheh1212 are not valid. My codes only accepts numbers.;))

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression replace to remove any commas, and parseInt() to change the resulting string into a number.

```
parseInt(yourVariable.replace(/\,/g,''),10)
```

Note that the result might still fail because obviously your users can type any old nonsense into the field. Read the doco on parseInt().

Comment: That field only accepts numbers and .00's.. it doesnt accept asdfghjqwretfjerhkltjert and it doesnt accepts !#$%&*()))(&^^)(+:"{ too. ;)) So if they're gonna put nonsense stuffs, its a MUST that its a number not whatever nonsense stuffs they want to. Thanks!

Comment: If you've already validated the format on input than you're halfway there. If you're validating on keyup or something like that don't forget to allow for the user pasting in invalid characters via the context menu.

Comment: Hi thanks nnnnnn ;)) Its already coded that asdfjweiorw,etc and %&^&**(*() and 123heheh1212 are not valid. My codes only accepts numbers.;))